# Can I select individual Items from a list?

Tags: c#, list, indexing

I have a list of strings and I need to select certain parts of the list to construct a separate string. What I have is:

```
name,gender,haircolour,car;
or
John,Male,Brown,toyota;
```

I also have a separate file indicating which parts, and in what order the new string should be constructed.

eg: `Index = 0,3,1` would print `John,toyota,Male` or `1,2,0` would print `Male,Brown,John`.

I have tried several methods to try and select the index of the items I want, but all the functions that return values only return the contents of the List, and the only return that gives an integer is `Count()`, which I can't see as being helpful.

I have tried and tried but all I have succeeded in doing is confusing myself more and more. Can anyone help suggest a way to achieve this?

Comment: and what exactly have you tried? Please post some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to do list[i], where i is the index of the element you need. There are some examples here: http://www.dotnetperls.com/list

Comment: thanks for the link, I didn't think you could use `list[i]`, I thought that was for arrays only :)

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding the question correctly, something like this should do the job:

```
const string data = "John,Male,Brown,toyota";
const string order = "0,3,1";

string[] indexes = order.Split(',');
string result = indexes.Aggregate("", (current, index) => current + data.Split(',')[int.Parse(index)] + ",");
result = result.TrimEnd(',');
```

If your string data ends with a semicolon `';'`, as possibly indicated in your question, then change the line to this:

```
string result = indexes.Aggregate("", (current, index) => current + data.Split(',')[int.Parse(index)].TrimEnd(';') + ",");
```

Note this solution doesn't check to make sure that the given index exists in the given data string. To add a check to make sure the index doesn't go over the array bounds, do something like this instead:

```
string result = indexes.Where(z => int.Parse(z) < data.Split(',').Length).Aggregate("", (current, index) => current + data.Split(',')[int.Parse(index)].TrimEnd(';') + ",");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<string> list = new List<string> { "John", "Male", "Brown", "toyota" };
        List<int> indexList = new List<int> { 0, 3, 1 };
        List<string> resultList = new List<string>();
        indexList.ForEach(i => resultList.Add(list[i]));
```